# Using .limitToFirst or .limitToLast still returns the whole data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter-web

First of all I'm new in Stackoverflow and in coding in Flutter Web. Here is my Flutter doctor:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.13.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-US)
>   [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
>   [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
>   [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
>   [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>   [✓] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
>   [✓] Connected device (3 available)
>   
>   • No issues found!

Now I got a database that looks like this:

[image: Realtime DB Datasets]

What I'm trying to do is to query the artwork's children according to its 'timestamp/seconds' like this:

```
fbDB = database();
fbArtworkRef = fbDB.ref('artworks');

await fbArtworkRef
    .orderByChild('last_updated/seconds')
    .limitToLast(10)
    .once(('value'))
    .then((value) {
  value.snapshot.forEach((child) {
    print(child.val());
  });
});
```

Look at the picture below:

[image: RealtimeUsage]

So whole data is 843.9KB.. And notice that when I executed the above code, which I get 10 artwork children in return (about 3KB), but in the Usage it shows 858.6KB. This means it downloaded the whole artworks node with all its children (plus the overhead) and then in the client side it will sort the list.

So the questions: 
1. How can I really just download those 10 pieces of data instead of getting everything?
2. Is it also the same behavior with Flutter App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
fbDB = database();
fbArtworkRef = fbDB.ref('artworks');

await fbArtworkRef
    .orderByChild('last_updated/seconds')
    .startAt(1572370553)
    .once(('value'))
    .then((value) {
  value.snapshot.forEach((child) {
    print(child.val());
  });
});
```

into this:

```
fbDB = database();
fbArtworkRef = fbDB.ref('artworks');

await fbArtworkRef
    .orderByChild('last_updated/seconds')
    .equalTo(1560908950)
    .once(('value'))
    .then((value) {
  value.snapshot.forEach((child) {
    print(child.val());
  });
});
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/query.dart#L137

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanna get that 10 children (instead of just one).

Comment: which 10 children do you want?

Comment: `child.val()` will give you the 10 children

Comment: And I'm not sure if this really just return one data from cloud, or it returns all then in the client side it cuts the rest.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear enough, but in my question above I have explained.. its not about returning the 10 children. I know how to get the 10 children and I got it. But when I get the 10 children in the usage meter (in Firebase console), it shows the size of the whole node downloaded instead of just ten (which supposed to be around 90KB instead of 858KB)

Comment: Did you try the answer? It will solve ur problem of downloading the whole data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So apparently using .limitToLast or .limitToFirst does not cut the size of the downloaded data. Instead we must use .startAt or .endAt or .equalTo which will return data specific to that query. And so I also fixed the title of this question accordingly

Comment: Sure, please up vote me too. If I may add, actually the full answer is that limitToLast and limitToFirst still returns all data. Thus we need the equalTo or startAt and endAt to really limit the number of data returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204387/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-zk-regen).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it has to download the entire data is because you want to sort before limiting. For the system to sort, it will require to download the entire data and then perform the sort.

However, if you are to limit first then sort, it will only download the first 10 items and only sort those 10 items.

Solution: If you really want to sort the entire list based on a child value, there is no workaround so youll have to stick to this OR change your data structure to be classified maybe by Year/Month